# Regular Expression for HEX format

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to create a regular expression for this format:
"0x3E,0xFf,0X32,0xaB"
The string has to begin "0" after that "x" or "X" after that 2 digit in hex (Upper case or not) and after that ",".
***the string ends without ",";***
This is what I got so far **"(0[xX][a-fA-F0-9]{2},)+"**
But It's not working....

Comment: not working means what?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  There's a good chance that a regex isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with following regex:

```
/^(0x[0-9a-f]{2})(,0x[0-9a-f]{2})*$/i
```

Comment: What is the "i" in the end?

Comment: @cheziHoyzer It allows both upper- and lowercase characters to be matched.

Comment: Thank you! this format supposed to work in JavaScript?              var patt = new RegExp("/^(0x[0-9a-f]{2})(,0x[0-9a-f]{2})*$/i");
    var res = patt.test(str);

Comment: @cheziHoyzer You can even try with: `var patt = /^(0x[0-9a-f]{2})(,0x[0-9a-f]{2})*$/i; patt.test(str);`

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't outline *why* you need to do this, but I can imagine that you'd ultimately want to parse out the valid hex numbers from the comma-separated string.  In that case something like this would be easier and more robust than a regex, in my opinion:

```
'0x3E,0xFf,0X32,0xaB,0xxaB,xyz'.split(',').filter(function(token) { return parseInt(token, 16); });
//returns ["0x3E", "0xFf", "0X32", "0xaB"]
```

If you really just want to check whether or not all of the values are valid hex, replace `filter` with `every`:

```
'0x3E,0xFf,0X32,0xaB'.split(',').every(function(token) { return parseInt(token, 16); });
//returns true

'0x3E,0xFf,0X32,0xaB,xyz'.split(',').every(function(token) { return parseInt(token, 16); });
//returns false
```